# Use of nextElementSibling - updating one input box based on value input of another

Tags: javascript, forms, datatables, nextsibling

I am using the following script on a form with multiple results to automatically enter a mark based on the percentage scored in a test.  The scripts works fine but only if the input box and the output box are adjacent.  I need to lay the score sheet out in a table - or divs but whenever I separate the inputs & outputs by placing them in table cells, the script breaks down.  I need the function to work on over thirty pairs of text inputs. Any help appreciated.

```
<td>
<input type="number" name="mod1a_s" class="input_select_teala_ltxt" id="mod1a_s" value="<?php echo $foo ?>" min="0" max="100" oninput="updateInputBox2(this)"/>
</td>

<td><input type="number"  name="mod1_s" class="input_select_teal_ltxt" id="mod1_s" max="3" min="0" step="1" value="<?php echo $foo ?>" /></td>
```

```
<script>
    function updateInputBox2(inputBox) {
      // Get the value from the current input box
      var inputValue = parseFloat(inputBox.value);

      // Find the corresponding output box
      var outputBox = inputBox.nextElementSibling;

      // Check the range and update the output box accordingly
      var outputBoxValue;
      if (inputValue >= 90) {
        outputBoxValue = 3;
      } else if (inputValue >= 80 && inputValue <= 89) {
        outputBoxValue = 2;
      } else if (inputValue >= 70 && inputValue <= 79) {
        outputBoxValue = 1;
      } else {
        outputBoxValue = 0;
      }

      // Update the value in the corresponding output box
      outputBox.value = outputBoxValue;
    }
  </script>
```

I would like to adapt the function further so that it can be used with tables or other layout objects. I have tried rewriting the code in various ways but with no success.  I am sure I am missing something obvious!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest allows you to navigate up to a common ancestor element first, and then you can use `querySelector` to find an element based on whatever proper criterion you have, in there.

Comment: The output box is `inputBox.parentElement.nextElementSibling.children[0]`

Comment: What you're missing are that the input elements are not siblings, they're cousins. Their parents are siblings.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `getElementById()` or `querySelector()` to find needed element (output). This will let you position your element wherever you want it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).